# how to sudoers drop_caches w/o proxy script?

Tags: sudo, cache

not `echo 3 |sudo -k tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` as we cant ensure if it will be "3" the value passed.
So, from where could I grantedly get the "3" text and how to write it at drop_caches w/o requiring a root owned read only proxy script?

Comment: what problem are you actually trying to solve?  why do you think that echo-ing `3` isn't going to reliably output `3`?   what do you mean by "proxy script"?

Comment: @cas the echo command isn't constrained so a user could do `echo 1 | sudo ... ` and send other data.

Comment: That's why, if you care about security or about restricting what users can do as root, you don't let users run `tee`, or other general purpose tools directly with `sudo`.  You only let them run wrapper scripts that each do one very specific thing, e.g. `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, with no (or very few) options and no trust of user-supplied data.  And if you need need to do something different? Write another wrapper script that does just that one new thing.   You can't stop stupid or carelessness or incompetence, you can only limit the risk and mitigate the damage.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this proved to be consistent on every boot:
The 1st byte of `/proc/3/stat` file.
So I put this on sudoers:
`sudo dd if=/proc/3/stat of=/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches bs=1 count=1`

Any other possibly more granted place to grab "3" from?

Comment: Giving a user access to run `dd` with `sudo` is something that needs extreme caution....dd can easily wipe any file, or any disk or other block device. not a good idea, better to write a wrapper script that runs `dd` with very specific options, and allow the user to run that script (but not dd itself) as root.  That's the normal, secure way to use sudo.

Comment: @cas the sudoers entry can be defined to exactly that one specific command and options, so only that can be used, and no other.  You don't have to (and shouldn't!) grant unrestricted access to dd

Comment: This answer may be better as an edit to the original question, because you're still asking "is there another way" at the end.  FWIW, not every OS (eg CentOS 7) will  have a PID 3, so you're dependent on a specific configuration.

Comment: @StephenHarris yes, that's true. `sudo` can be configured like that.  It's easier (and, IMO, much safer) to just write wrapper scripts (or single-purpose programs that do only one specific thing).   `/etc/sudoers` is a PITA to edit, especially if you need to restrict not only WHAT can be run but the options that it can be run with.

Comment: @StephenHarris, oh good to know other OSs may not have a  PID 3, I think also PID 3 may end and not be available for any reason. I put as answer because it proved to be reliable in practice tho as til now, on ubuntu, it have worked everytime, but I know it has a possiblity to fail. But anyway, when I answer my own questions I usually ask for a better answer as I think my just discovered solution may be limited (because I just discovered it), so I hold on accepting and encourage others to help.